# How to configure Custom Attributes in SP metadata

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0

I came to know that in any SSO Solution if SP needs any additional attributes it can publish them in its metadata using *AttributeConsumingService* argument. The required attributes can now be added like as below:

```
<md:AttributeConsumingService index="0"
xmlns:md="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata"
xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
<md:ServiceName xml:lang="en">ABC</md:ServiceName>
<md:ServiceDescription xml:lang="en">ABC</md:ServiceDescription>
<md:RequestedAttribute isRequired="true"
NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri"
Name="urn:oid:2.5.4.42"
FriendlyName="FirstName"/>
</md:AttributeConsumingService>
```

Now, if I want to add a custom attribute in my SP metadata, lets say "Role" of a user, how should I add it in the metadata? I mean, what would be its Name(this is what I'm unable to find!), NameFormat(is it urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:uri?) and FriendlyName(can I give it as "Role" here?). I've not found anything related to this in the SAML2Core document.

Any suggestions please!

Thanks,

Abhilash

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no universal answer as it depends on which IDP/federation you use and what is supported by it.

Generally, the friendly name is just a human-readable identifier for the attribute and the value can be freely defined.

The NameFormat and Name are defined based on Attribute Profile used by your IDP (e.g. Basic profile, X.500/LDAP Profile, ...). The expected values can be found in [SAML 2.0 profiles document](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-profiles-2.0-os.pdf) chapter 8.

You can find an example of how this is employed in practice for e.g. inCommon federation in their [documentation](https://spaces.internet2.edu/display/InCFederation/Requested+Attributes).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! In my scenario, I've to prepare from SP-side the required metadata before reaching to any IdP. If the IDP supports Basic profile (just assuming), though it may be capable of sending only some certain attributes which are configured at its end, is it possible to ask for any custom (like "Role") attributes from SP-end(by publishing them in my metadata)? So in that case what would be the Name of my custom attribute? (Hope you got what I need!)

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong with this: Any IDP is configured to send certain Attributes which it can do on request from SP(specified in metadata). If any SP needs any new additional attributes(like Role), it is IDP's responsibility to generate them and publish the Name, NameFormat and FriendlyName of that attribute (like inCommon Federation did) so that SP can now configure that new attributes in its metadata with those parameters given by IDP. So it's the sole responsibility of IDP to generate new attributes and there is no way an SP can ask them in the metadata without IDP creating them!

Comment: Some IDPs are configured to send Attributes based on request from SP specified in metadata, but not all IDPs. When such feature is supported, then yes, it is IDPs responsibility to publish the supported Name, NameFormat and FriendlyName values just like you say.